# Zoom and move image with code

Tags: c#, wpf, image, zooming

I have an `image` inside a `border` and I would like to show different parts of the image source in the image box at different times. Specifically, when a certain textbox gets focus, I want to change the image so it zooms to a certain portion of the image content.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="5" Height="504"   
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,116,0,0" Name="border1"  
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" ClipToBounds="True">
   <Image Height="493" Name="image5" Stretch="Fill" Width="390" 
       ClipToBounds="True" BindingGroup="{Binding}" 
       Clip="{Binding ElementName=border1}" 
       Cursor="Hand" StretchDirection="Both" />
</Border>
```

For an example, my image source is 2550 x 3320 pixels. I would like the `image` box to show the source in a rectangle starting at point 1755,300 with width of 650 and height of 230. I do not want to use CloneBitmap to cut that rectangle out and display it because I also have a manual zoom set up for this `image` where the user can use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out and click & drag to pan the image. I still want to allow that after we zoom to desired area.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried implementing colinsmith's answer, but whenever I change the scrollviewer's offsets, It chops the image, so if I later move (click and drag to pan) it, it's empty space. I've had this working before with just the image inside the scrollviewer, but now I have an image inside a scrollviewer inside a border. The border is necessary for my zoom and pan as I have it set up now.

My updated XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="5" Height="504" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,116,0,0" Name="border1"   
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" ClipToBounds="True">

   <ScrollViewer x:Name="image5scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
      <Image Height="493" Name="image5" Stretch="Fill" Width="390" 
         ClipToBounds="True" BindingGroup="{Binding}" 
         Clip="{Binding ElementName=image5scroll}" Cursor="Hand" 
         StretchDirection="Both" />
   </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

And code behind:

```
public void imageZoom(Element element, int index)
{
   if (element.Rectangle.Left - 100 > 0)
   {
      image5scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(element.Rectangle.Left - 100);
      image5scroll.Width = element.Rectangle.Width + 200;
      image5scroll.Height = element.Rectangle.Height + 200;
      border1.Width = image5scroll.Width;
      border1.Height = image5scroll.Height;
      image5.Width = image5scroll.Width;
      image5.Height = image5scroll.Height;
      image5.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
   }
   else
     {
        image5scroll.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
     }

   if (element.Rectangle.Top - 100 > 0)
   {
      image5scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(element.Rectangle.Top - 100);
   }
   else
      {
         image5scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
      }
}
```

Comment: The documentation is lacking, but is it the [VisualClip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualclip) or [VisualOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualoffset.aspx) properties that can set the position the image is shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ScrollViewer to wrap your Image...then you can tell the ScrollViewer to go to a vertical and horizontal offset by calling the `ScrollToVerticalOffset()` and `ScrollToHorizontalOffset()` methods (as there isn't a property which you can set).

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="5" Height="504"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,116,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="image5scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Image Height="493" Name="image5" Stretch="None" Width="390" BindingGroup="{Binding}"
            Cursor="Hand" Source="http://www.noaanews.noaa.gov/stories/images/goes-12-firstimage-large081701.jpg"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>  
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

However, if you must be be able to set the position of the ScrollViewer using properties instead of code-behind then a solution is to define an Attached Property which does the calls to ScrollToVerticalOffset/ScrollToHorizontalOffset for you underneath.

- http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/how-to-set-wpf-scrollviewer-verticaloffset-and-horizontal-offset/

Comment: I have updated the question to add attempted implementation of this answer.

Comment: You don't want to do any stretching...you want to scroll the image as it is but see a viewport into that image....so set Stretch="None"

Comment: When I change Stretch to None, my image is chopped at the width and height. When I pan it, everything below and to the right is just white space.

Comment: Don't change the image width and height...you need the image at it's full size...the scrollviewer will handle which part you see. Take out these lines:                image5.Width = image5scroll.Width;
                image5.Height = image5scroll.Height; from your imageZoom

Comment: To do zooming as well as scrolling, then you'd need to scale the image with a transform....set that transform to shrink or expand the image. e.g. http://joewoodblog.com/2011/01/21/29/ .... Or you can use this control. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning

Comment: I've tried those options without success. I finally decided it would be pretty simple to just change the margins of the image within the border. However, my image is still getting clipped when I have Stretch = None. I am no longer changing the image width or height at any time in code behind or in the initial XAML.